# Run ScrollTop with offset of element by ID

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Trying to make the browser scroll to a specific ID with an added offset -

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top}, 'slow');
```

What I need to do is to set the offset by -100px. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

No magic involved, just subtract from the offset top of the element

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top -100 }, 'slow');
```

Comment: Use window.innerHeight to determine the user's screen height.

Comment: @Phillip what does screen height have to do with anything in this instance?

Comment: If the page is long, and you have a submit button at the bottom of the page, you can scroll to the submit button and stop at the bottom of the user's visible window.

Comment: Thanks for this, one of those things I knew but simply forgot how easy it was.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      var target = $(this.hash);
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 120
        }, 'linear');   
  });    
    if (location.hash){
    var id = $(location.hash);
    }
    $(window).on('load', function() {
    if (location.hash){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: id.offset().top -120}, 'linear')
    };
    });
});
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var top = ($(".apps_intro_wrapper_inner").offset() || { "top": NaN }).top;   
if (!isNaN(top)) {
$("#app_scroler").click(function () {   
$('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: top
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

if you want to scroll a little above or below from specific div that add value to the top like this.....like I add 800

```
var top = ($(".apps_intro_wrapper_inner").offset() || { "top": NaN }).top + 800;
```

Answer (score 0):

no logic involve only need subtraction with -215 and it's exact put my div properly at top postion

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top -215},'slow');
```