# CTRL +F functionality to have hitting enter take you to next highlighted item

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to apply a `CTRL + F` function to my site.

I have managed to write code to highlight all the matching items in the list. I am using `REgex` to find matches in a list. Now I want to make it scroll to the items one by one by hitting enter. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: This answer may be of some help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618997/run-scrolltop-with-offset-of-element-by-id

Comment: Well, I have done things to scroll the page to the desired div. I want the page to scroll to another match on hitting enter again.