# tbody focus does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, focus

I have the following table structure:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th> </th>
  <th> </th>
  <th> </th>

</tr>
<tbody id="page-1">
 <tr>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>    
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>    
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="page-2">
 <tr>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td>  </td>    
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried the following jquery code to make scroll to specific `tbody` by `id` like:

```
page = 1;
$("#page-"+page).focus()
```

The above code failed to make scroll to the specified `tbody`. I also tried the following in order to get first `tr` but also failed:

```
page = 1;
$("#page-"+page+":first-child").focus()
```

The last thing that I have to mention, that `tbody` is loaded via ajax request and `console.log($("#page-"+page).html())` works fine and prints out the html of the `tbody`

Comment: i think you try with function `on`.All jquery event not working for element render after document read.

Comment: As I mention `console.log()` works, so the elements, I think, known by the DOM! @DatNguyen

Comment: because `console.log` is javascript base.But `jQuery` code not works.

Comment: You can readmore here `http://api.jquery.com/on/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the mistake. `focus` is not the suitable event for `tbody` in other words there is no point of focus for it. The solution is [Run ScrollTop with offset of element by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618997/run-scrolltop-with-offset-of-element-by-id) and using:

```
$('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $('#page-'+page).offset().top -100
                }, 2000);
```