# IPhone / IPad : Vanilla JS scrollTop isn't working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Vue CLI 3 , Vue 2.5.17

I want to scroll to Specific div element when RestApi response is success. But my code isn't working to IOS devices.

I try to "scroll", "scrollTo" and "scrollTop" functions. But those functions aren't working.

```
 const el = document.querySelector(selector)

 // Custom Scroll Class Method
 Scroll.scrollIt(el, 200, 'linear')

 // Common ScrollTo Method
 document.querySelector('html', 'body')
   .scrollTo({
     top: (el.offsetTop - 90),
     left: 0,
     behavior: 'smooth'
   })
```

ScrollIt function is a custom Scroll class method.

```
export default class Scroll {
  public static scrollIt (element: HTMLElement, duration: number, callback?: Function) {
    const start = document.querySelector('document, html, body').scrollTop
    const change = element.offsetTop - start
    let currentTime = 0
    const increment = 20

    const animateScroll = function () {
      currentTime += increment
      const val = easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration)
      document.querySelector('document, html, body').scrollTop = val - 90
      if (currentTime < duration) {
        setTimeout(animateScroll, increment)
      }
    }
    animateScroll()

    // t = current time
    // b = start value
    // c = change in value
    // d = duration
    function easeInOutQuad (t: number, b: number, c: number, d: number) {
      t /= d/2
      if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b
      t--
      return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error message on the [JS console](https://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/)?

Comment: Why dont you try it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618997/run-scrolltop-with-offset-of-element-by-id

Comment: @FabianLaure Unfortunately, there is no error message in the js console.

Comment: @Manticore,  I don't use Jquery Animate because not included jquery in my project.

Comment: I quickly made a fiddle out of this: https://jsfiddle.net/y1jboqrn/

Comment: In the fiddle it is working on chrome. What browser do you have troubles with? safari on iOS?

Comment: @Manticore, the code is not working on chrome and safari of Iphone 6S Plus. I know to working the code but i don't understand to why doesn't it scroll to specific div.